# The "MediaType" type isn't defined

Tags: flutter, api, dart, httprequest, multipartform-data

From the below code I tried to upload Two Images and 1 json fields to the given API.
but the Api returs the response of 415-Unsupported media format so tried to change the content type while i tried i cant define the values for content-type parameter in mulipartfile.frombytes method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Ask the API provider. We cannot possibly know what propted them to return a specific error code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.